# Formatting of 'this' pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, this

To be honest `(*this)` looks a lot better than `this->`. They both function the same. Why shouldn't I use the former? Is it just common practice to use `this->`, or is there something more to it?

Comment: Why use either? It's implicit anyway.

Comment: I think it looks worse, I suspect that most would agree with me.

Comment: Are you asking "Should I do `(*this).field` instead of `this->field`?" - if that is the question then the answer is NO (but then it is opinion based and everyone is entitled to their own opinion even if it is wrong ;-)

Comment: @Johnathan Potter Setting class members of the same name with function arguments, for instance. Plus explicit is easier to understand than implicit.

Comment: "Is it just common practice to use `this->`" – the `->` operator was invented *exactly* because `(*foo).bar` is ugly and harder to read than `foo->bar`. When you have written and read enough code, you will be enlightened.

Comment: It's not common practise to use this at all in the way you are describing. Sometimes you just have to go with the majority view even if you don't agree with it.

Comment: A common practise which addresses both of your concerns is to make the names of data members diffierent in some way. For instance you can use the prefix 'my' for all data members. E.g. instead of `this->pudding = pudding;` write `myPudding = pudding;`.

Comment: I follow the tracks of logic from right to left as a member-of a pointer to this object. Then again I do have ADD so it may just be my attention span. I'll keep the opinion about the subject in mind where I collaborate, thanks.

Comment: (*) are three shifted characters, with an unshifted word in between, -> only one shifted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually both will have same results when accessing data-members. Though you find `(*this)` more elegant I would undoubtedly say most will disagree.

Comment: You are fighting against the convention. If `(*this).xxx` came to me in either a code review or school assignment, you'd be changing it to `this->xxx`.

Comment: @john read the answer carefully